# unable to over ride Bootstrap Popover hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to build website. but i am stuck with a problem with popovers.

In a form input field, I have applied the popover and it is working fine. but when the user clicks on the input field again, the popover hides.

Now,  I want it to stay forever until I do a custom action.

I could not find any related scenario on the web. 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try show div again of click with your custom code like:

```
$('#yourInputId').on('click', function(){
      $('yourPopupId').show();
});
```

OR you can find this input bind in bootstrap code and then delete it rome there.(I'm talking about not minified version)